# How can I interpolate this?

Tags: php, arrays

I need to get a set of dates, that doesn't have dots between month and year to use them in a jQuery function.
First I have to get the dataset from an SQL server with this method:

```
public function dataLoop($res, $farbenzuordnung ){ 

    while ( $line = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $res ) ) { 
   
        $button = convert_trigger (  $line[ 'hotornot_trigger' ] , $farbenzuordnung );
        $monate = date("n.y", $line[ 'hotornot_time']);  
        $months_without_p = date("ny", $line[ 'hotornot_time']); // this is where i get the requiered dataset
        $this->months_withoutpoint[ $monate ] = $months_without_p; 

        $this->anzahl = hochzaelen($this->anzahl, $line['hotornot_trigger']); 
  
        if ( isset($this->inhalt [$monate]) === FALSE ) { 
            $this->inhalt [$monate] = [];
        }
        if ( isset($this->inhalt [$monate][$button]) === FALSE ) {
            $this->inhalt [$monate][$button] = 0;
        }
        $this->inhalt [$monate] [$button] +=1 ; 
    }
}
```

I access the $pointless variable from my index.php like this:

```
$pointless = $sql_database -> months_withoutpoint;
```

At this point, print_r ($pointless); outputs this:

```
Array ( 
    [2.21] => 221 
    [3.21] => 321 
    [4.21] => 421 
    [5.21] => 521 
    [6.21] => 621 
) 
Array ( 
    [2.21] => 221 
    [3.21] => 321 
    [4.21] => 421 
    [5.21] => 521 
    [6.21] => 621 
)
```

I later use string interpolation with a custom str_replace function:

```
$sql_format -> template_substitution ( '{MONTHS_WITHOUT_POINT}' ,$pointless  );
```

In this repeater-HTML-file, that gets looped over:

```
    <div onclick="klappen( {MONTHS_WITHOUT_POINT} )" style="border:1px solid black; width:100%;background-color: yellow;"><ul id="{MONTHS_WITHOUT_POINT}" style="display:none">
    <li>{MONAT} </li>
    <ul>
        <li> {FARBE} </li>
        <li> [ANZAHL_LISTE] </li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

I get Array to string conversion notices though, and the {MONTHS_WITHOUT_POINT} strings don't get replaced. What do I have to do to only get the value without the points from $pointless?

Comment: if you mean `onclick="klappen( {MONTHS_WITHOUT_POINT} )"` renders to `onclick="klappen( Array )"`, then you should json_encode it

Comment: I'm suposed to do it without json encoding sadly. It should work by simply working on the php portion

Answer (score 0):

As i can see, when you use `$sql_database -> months_withoutpoint;`  you receive an array with key=2.21 and val=221, so if you want to get only the values you have to use `array_value($pointless)` and you will get an array like:

```
[
   221,
   321,
   421,
   ...
]
```

Comment: This turns the output into: 
Array ( [0] => 221 [1] => 321 [2] => 421 [3] => 521 [4] => 621 ) 
Still the same error messages and result though

Comment: the problem is that you need to pass a string (or number) to your function, so you have to cycle on this array and get the single element. i don't understood how you cycle the elements when you say "In this repeater-HTML-file, that gets looped over:" but basically, you have to do this `$sql_format -> template_substitution ( '{MONTHS_WITHOUT_POINT}' ,$pointless[$i]  );` or something like that, where $i is you loop index. if the cycle is after you can get the current element by `klappen( {MONTHS_WITHOUT_POINT[$i]} )`